# boost::program_options config file format

Tags: c++, boost, delimiter, file-format, boost-program-options

I am using boost::program_options to load command line arguments. Now I want to additionally load a config file with the same arguments set. I use it in very standard way:

```
ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
if (ifs) {
    po::store(po::parse_config_file(ifs, optionsDescription), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
}
```

The thing is that parse_config_file accepts ini files in following standard format:

```
key1=value
key2 = value
```

But my file does not use "equal sign" to separate key and value but only spaces and/or tabs like this:

```
key1 value
key2  value
```

I need to keep this format for compatibility reason. Is there any way to achieve this with boost program_options?
I have found style option of command_line parses, but there seems to be nothing like that for parse_config_file.

Comment: Maybe you could then read your file and store in memory the different options (a la `argv`) and feed that to `command_line_parser`?

Comment: Something like that will be maybe needed if there is no standard supported way. To store in memory and reformat to standard ini format (add equal sign instead of first delimiter of each line) or to feed the command line parser (add minus minus signs in front of every line). Not very nice but doable if no other option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [source code](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/develop/src/config_file.cpp), boost seems looking for `=` symbol explicitly.

So there is no direct way to handle your file format. You might have to change boost source or load file to memory and handle values as command line input.

```
else if ((n = s.find('=')) != string::npos) {
    string name = m_prefix + trim_ws(s.substr(0, n));
    string value = trim_ws(s.substr(n+1));

    bool registered = allowed_option(name);
    if (!registered && !m_allow_unregistered)
        boost::throw_exception(unknown_option(name));

    found = true;
    this->value().string_key = name;
    this->value().value.clear();
    this->value().value.push_back(value);
    this->value().unregistered = !registered;
    this->value().original_tokens.clear();
    this->value().original_tokens.push_back(name);
    this->value().original_tokens.push_back(value);
    break;

}
```

Comment: Thank you miradham. So I am loading it to memory and processing it with command_line_parser. There has to be some trim and inside whitespace duplications handling (std::remove, unique, isspace...), splitting while respecting the quotes (boost tokenizer and escaped_list_separator), adding "--" to make it cmd format and such things, so not so elegant as I was hoping for, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, but the input config file was a basic CSV file (ie. no quote support to handle values that contain commas).

My solution, riffing on what miradham wrote above, was to pass the input file stream through a `filtering_istream` and apply a simple regex filter that translated ',' into '='.

If down the road we need to add values with commas, then I would probably have to implement my own `filtering_istream` (I understand it is a template) that could handle this more complex scenario.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

...

// do we have a config file?
if (vm.count("config"))
{
    std::ifstream fConfig{ vm["config"].as<std::string>().c_str() };
    if (fConfig)
    {
        // prep_config = filtered stream, replacing ',' with '='
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream prep_config;
        prep_config.push(boost::iostreams::regex_filter{ boost::regex{","}, "="});
        prep_config.push(fConfig);

        po::store(parse_config_file( prep_config, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the configuration file - ignoring.\n";
    }
}
// drop through to the main configuration interpretation
```